# Why is the causative used here?

Tags: grammar

This is a dialogue from Death Note. A guy is being asked to analyze some items.

> Guy 1: これの鑑識お願いできますか?
> Guy 2: 鑑識には顔が利く、徹底的に調べさせます

I don't understand what the causative is supposed to function as here. Nobody is being made to do something, nor allowed to do something, Guy 1 simply asks Guy 2 to analyze the items, and Guy 2 accepts and says that he will do it thoroughly.

My guesses are that, perhaps the usage here is similar to させてもらう, as in (I will take the liberty of) kind of meaning, and since Guy 2 is in a lower position here, it sounds even more appropriate (I will take the liberty of letting myself do the investigation).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 鑑識には顔が利く、徹底的に調べさせます

means

> （私が）鑑識（課）には顔が利く。（私が鑑識課に）徹底的に調べさせます。
> "I have contacts in the crime lab. I will have them analyze the items thoroughly."

鑑識 in this line means 鑑識課, "crime lab". From 明鏡国語辞典:

> 鑑識
> ➋ 犯罪捜査で、指紋・声紋・足跡・血痕などの資料を科学的に調べること。**また、その係。**

---

(But 鑑識 in 「これの鑑識お願いできますか？」 means "identification".)